# Java Search all possible combo lists in the array (Algorithm)

Tags: java, string, performance, algorithm, design-patterns

I am trying to find a list of all possible combinations of elements in an array.

For example, let us consider an array with the following elements: 'A','B','C','D' .

If I choose a number for the maximum string length, then I want to get all combinations of arrays up to the maximum length. For example:

5 = Maximum number; then: A , AA, AAA, AAAA, AAAAA , AAAAB , AAAAC ....... DDDDD

I made a code. Its speed is ok until the maximum number is 10. For more than 15, it starts to be very slow.

Does someone have a better idea to make it faster?

This is my code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    HashSet<String> allResults = new HashSet<String>();
    // Create an alphabet to work with
    char[] alphabet = new char[] {'A','B','C','D'};
    // Find all possible combinations of this alphabet in the string size of 3
    StringExcersise.possibleStrings(15, alphabet,"", allResults);
    System.out.println(allResults.size());
}


    class StringExcersise {

public static void possibleStrings(int maxLength, char[] alphabet, String curr, HashSet<String> allResults) {
    // If the current string has reached it's maximum length
    if(curr.length() == maxLength) {
        allResults.add(curr);
        //System.out.println(curr);

    // Else add each letter from the alphabet to new strings and process these new strings again
    } else {
        for(int i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
            String oldCurr = curr;
            if(!allResults.contains(oldCurr))
                allResults.add(oldCurr);
            curr += alphabet[i];
            possibleStrings(maxLength,alphabet,curr,allResults);
            curr = oldCurr;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Any algorithm will slow down, because your solution space is in the order of 5 to the power (n+1), which for n=15 is over a trillion.

Comment: @Bohemian Oh really? That's huge.. Then I may need to think about it how to reduce possible combination.. :)

Comment: By the way, probably using `+=` on `String` isn't the best choice if you need performances, and maybe a `StringBuilder` can be a better choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out `Heap's Algorithm` [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm)

A working example in Java:

```
    private static void swap(int[] v, int i, int j) {
        int temp = v[i]; 
            v[i] = v[j];
            v[j] = temp;
    }

    public void permute(int[] v, int n) {
        if (n == 1) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(v));
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                permute(v, n-1);
                if (n % 2 == 1) {
                    swap(v, 0, n-1);
                } else {
                    swap(v, i, n-1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: A modification of [this](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD05xx/EWD502.html) algorithm would probably do the trick.

Comment: It's not a exactly answer that I wanted but one of option that I might think :) thanks